# Is using 1 die when all but 1 piece is in home and the last piece near home ok, or do I use both dice like usual?

Tags: parcheesi

Parcheesi is a race between four players. Each player moves four pawns from their starting point, around the board and then into the center.

In Parcheesi, is it possible to use just 1 die at the end rather than 2 for moves less than 7 spaces? I play by the rules, and there is no rule on dice usage at the end of the game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is no specific rule that allows you to change the dice usage at the end of the game, then you must roll the dice as always. However, after reading the rules more carefully, rolling only one die would actually be a disadvantage. The dies are used separately, not necessarily added together to move. That is, if you are 3 spaces away (a move less than 7 as you stated) and you roll a 4 and a 3, you use the 3 and it's done.

From this [website](http://howdoyouplayit.com/parcheesi-rules-play-parcheesi/)...

> Die may be combined to move one piece, or may be used separately to
>   move separate pieces, but you may not split a singular die to move two
>   pieces.